# How to convert image mask recieved from SAM model to a polygon which is the outline of the mask?

Tags: reactjs, image-segmentation, onnxruntime

Im using SAM andd onnxruntime-web with reactjs to detect object in real time with semantic segmentation,i get the image mask from the model,which i mshowing on image,but i want to get the borders /outline of the mask as a polygon

what i tried is looping through the pixels of the image mask and checking and getting the border,but it takes time to do so,so im looking  for some other way

```
async function onnxMaskToPolygon(input, width, height) {
    const result = (await extractPolygon(await arrayToImageData(input, width, height), [0, 114, 189, 255]))
    return result
}

async function arrayToImageData(input, width, height) {
    const [r, g, b, a] = [0, 114, 189, 255]; // the masks's blue color
    const arr = new Uint8ClampedArray(4 * width * height).fill(0);

    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if (input[i] > 0.0) {
            arr[4 * i + 0] = r;
            arr[4 * i + 1] = g;
            arr[4 * i + 2] = b;
            arr[4 * i + 3] = a;
        }
    }

    return new ImageData(arr, height, width);
}

async function imageDataToImage(imageData) {
    const canvas = imageDataToCanvas(imageData);
    const image = new Image();
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL();
    return image;
}

function imageDataToCanvas(imageData) {
    const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.width = imageData.width;
    canvas.height = imageData.height;
    if (ctx) ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    return canvas;
}

const extractPolygon = async (imageData, targetColor) => {
    console.log("enter in extract...")
    const { width, height, data } = imageData;
    console.log("image data", imageData)
    const polygon = new Set();

    const targetColorString = targetColor.join(',');

    // Iterate through the image data and find the boundary of the target color
    for (let y = 0; y < height; y++) {
        for (let x = 0; x < width; x++) {
            const index = (y * width + x) * 4; // Each pixel has 4 values (R, G, B, A)
            const currentColor = data.slice(index, index + 4);

            if (currentColor.join(',') === targetColorString) {
                // Found a pixel with the target color
                // Add its position to the polygon
                polygon.add(`${x},${y}`);
            }
        }
    }
    console.log("after foor loop")
    // Convert the Set of strings into an array of objects with x and y
    const polygonArray = Array.from(polygon).map((point) => {
        const [x, y] = point.split(',').map(Number);
        return { x, y }
    });
    // console.log("polygon array", polygonArray)

    // return convexHull(polygonArray);
    // return concaveHull(polygonArray,100);
    console.log("before simplify...")
    const simplifiedPrediction = simplify(polygonArray, 5)
    console.log("before concave...", simplifiedPrediction)
    const outline = concaveman(simplifiedPrediction.map(points => [points.x, points.y]), 1)
    console.log("exiting extract polygon...")
    return outline

};
```